# JSF - Populating a drop down depending on value in other drop down

Tags: jsf

I need to populate a drop down based on the selected value in another drop down. I can use AJAX requests to do that but I am searching for a solution using JSF only. The values to populate the drop down need to come from a table every time user changes his selection.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the version, so I'll assume JSF 1.2. The `<a4j:support>` tag is part of [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces):

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="firstDropDown" value="#{bean.firstDropDownSelection}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}" />
   <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="secondDropDown" 
       immediate="true" action="#{bean.fetchItems2}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="secondDropDown" value="#{bean.secondDropDownSelection}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items2}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And in the method `bean.fetchItems2` you load your collection `items2` with the appropriate items.

What happens, is when the value of the first drop down changes, the second drop down is rerendered and its value is fetched from the server again.